# How to compile a java file which uses another java class that requires jar files?

Tags: java, jar, jakarta-mail, javac

I have written a java file(called SendEmail.java) which uses javax.mail.jar and javax.activator.jar for compilation and running.
Now I have written another java file(called Check.java) which imports SendEmail.
The problem I am facing here is while I am compiling Check.java. I compile it using the same classpath as I used while compiling SendEmail.java. The files are in a package called pack.

Command I use to compile SendEmail.java -

```
C:\Users\Myname\code\javafiles>javac -cp ".;.\pack\javax.activation.jar;.\pack\ja
vax.mail.jar;" pack\SendEmail.java
```

Command I use to compile Check.java -

```
C:\Users\Myname\code\javafiles>javac -cp ".;.\pack\javax.activation.jar;.\pack\ja
vax.mail.jar;" pack\Check.java
```

The error I am getting is-

```
C:\Users\Myname\code\javafiles>javac -cp ".;.\pack\javax.activation.jar;.\pack
\javax.mail.jar;" pack\Check.java  
pack\Check.java:3: error: cannot access SendEmail  
import pack.SendEmail.*;  
           ^
  bad class file: .\pack\SendEmail.class  
    class file contains wrong class: SendEmail  
    Please remove or make sure it appears in the correct subdirectory of the cla
sspath.
```

Comment: Not that it solves anything, but instead of `.\pack\javax.activation.jar;.\pack\javax.mail.jar;` you can use `pack\*` to add all `jar` files. Also try placing your `jar`s into separate directory than your code. It is good practice to have `lib` folder for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
javac -cp ".;.\pack\javax.activation.jar;.\pack\javax.mail.jar;" pack\Check.java
```

And yes, you should really move the jar files out of the directory containing your source and class files.

Comment: Changed the command to what you suggested. Still getting the same error. How should I proceed now?

Comment: I was discussing the code with a friend. Turns out that I hada made a mistake while includeing SendEmail.java in a package. 
So, ur solution worked. Thanks